# What is the maximum layer of subdirectory at codeigniter controllers

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a a project(codeigniter) where file directory is like that.

- mysite

  - application

    - config
  - controllers

    - super_admin

      - admin.php
    - tasks

      - setup

        - bank.php
    - assets.php

Now if I try to access

```
http://localhost/mysite/tasks/seutp/bank
```

It calls codeigniter `404 page`

But I can access

```
http://localhost/mysite/tasks/assets
```

Actually I can get access any controller under `controllers` and `controllers/tasks` folder.
But I cannot get access under `controllers/tasks/setup` folder
My question is

- Is there any limitation of sub-directory at codeigniter?
- If Yes: Is there any way to solve the limitation and How?
- If No: Why I cannot access the third layer sub-directory controllers?Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

yes there is a default for the ci controllers file folder levels. i am using this solution:

https://degreesofzero.com/article/controllers-in-sub-sub-folders-in-codeigniter.html

the author includes a lengthy mod rewrite but if you already have a working htaccess rewrite file to eliminate index.php from the url then it will probably work as is.